# How to reduce the speed of a single-phase induction motor

Tags: induction-motor, speed

I have a 1 h.p. single phase induction motor driving a dust extraction blower. The air flow is about 600 cubic feet per minute. The device that the dust collection duct is attached to requires only 300 CFM. I don't want to waste energy; is there an inexpensive way to reduce the fan speed to 300 CFM?

Update; I measured the flow in the duct yesterday with a hot-wire anemometer - it's actually only 245 CFM. 600 CFM is what's printed on the blower, but I guess it's either an inflated number, or the conductance of the duct system is limiting the flow.

Thank you all for the informative replies.

Comment: If it is not a multi speed motor, and there are no pulleys to change out, the answer is no. Typically AC motors follow the line phase, so without a VFD, to change the line frequency, it is impossible.

Comment: If it's a centrifugal blower, then it will use less power if you  partially block its outlet. You'll hear the fan speed increase slightly as you choke it, this indicates less slip and hence less power. Measuring the change in current won't be accurate as the power factor will change too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this old abandoned question as off-topic because the asker has discovered no reduction is actually appropriate and because there is little economically practical way to achieve the goal electrically.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple types of single phase true AC motors, only two of them can have their speed controlled without risking damage to the motor; Shaded Pole motors and Permanent Split Capacitor (PSC) types. Shaded Pole motors can be controlled by varying the voltage only, which lowers the torque and increases the slip, but since they are designed to deal with it, the motor itself does not overheat, it just does less work, but Shaded Pole motors typically stop at 1/4HP. PSC motors can be controlled with voltage control as well, but ONLY if the load is a centrifugal machine in which the load on the motor drops at the cube of the speed change. If you simply reduce the voltage of a PSC motor on something other than a centrifugal machine, it overloads and burns up. Not knowing what type of motor you have means the best advice is to not try this until you know for sure.

Also, "blowers" come in both centrifugal and positive displacement varieties, so from your simple description we can't determine if any of this is possible even if you do have a PSC motor.

A third type is a "Universal motor" that is actually a brushed DC motor designed to run from an AC input. Universal motors are the type found in portable power tools and small kitchen appliances with variable speeds. Again, not typical for that to come in a 1HP variety.

You can also control a PSC motor using a Variable Frequency Drive, but for 1HP 120V, the few that are out there that will work on a single phase motor will cost a LOT more than a new motor.

If your motor has a starting switch inside, i.e. when you turn it on, you hear a "click" right after it starts spinning, then it's one of the types that cannot be speed controlled.

Answer (score 0):

First be aware that the flow rate of fans relies on the square of the turn speed. So you had to reduce the speed to 70%, not 50%.

Unfortunately, the speed of an induction motor is mostly a function of the frequency and it's expensive to change that.

The second option would be a resistor in series. That would flatten the M/n ramp at the working point. But for a 30% speed reduction, this is a huge waste of energy.

The third option is reducing the voltage but you cannot apply it here because you usually only get at max 10% speed reduction unless the motor is specifically built for that. Unlikely for a fan drive.

So, think of the fourth option and mount a smaller fan on the same motor. That would waste no energy at all.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out single phase motors are hard to speed control.

It won't save any energy, but you could simply put a bleed opening in your inlet to control the CFM for your extractor.

Answer (score 0):

If you just reduce the flow rate (using an obstruction) that will reduce the load on the motor and thus the energy consumption.

Blowers a weird like that: try it with a vacuum cleaner some time, when you block the inlet (or outlet) the motor speeds up indicating that the mechanical load has been reduced.

another option is to use a smaller fan.

another is to reduce the supply voltage using a transformer or series capacitor, this will work with a blower because the mechanical load is not constant, but insted dependant on the motor speed.

Answer (score -1):

You can limit the current or alter the switching frequency of the power electronic switching controlling the motor.
see this article for better understanding: http://googleweblight.com/?ei=urhYp54c&host=www.google.co.in&lc=en-IN&lite_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.designnews.com%2Fdocument.asp%3Fdoc_id%3D221517&m=474&s=1&sig=AF9NedkX3SeigUoCrVRQPiu1OQD0zdzr5g&ts=1478342223

Comment: It better to put relavent information in the answer instead of in a link, in the future the link will die and the answer will be worthless

Comment: @laptop2d Especially when it's at "Google We Blight .com", sounds like a site that scrapes other websites and copies their content and puts ads on them. Fair guess the copied article's original is on www.DesignNews.com.